# How to avoid math rounding errors in Javascsript Browser environments

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I´ve come across this oddity when writing some JS code. It happens in both Chrome and Firefox:

10.04 + 0.01 = 10.049999999999999

[image: Chrome]

[image: Firefox]

Not sure if I´m just missing something obvious that causes this?

Right now I am handling it with rounding the number afterwards - Is there a better way to avoid this bug/feature?

Comment: A common solution is to work with them as integers. do all the math using the number as ints 1004 + 001. Once you have to print the number divide it by 100

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a consequence of the way numbers are stored internally in IEEE 754 form.

To avoid this, use a BigDecimal library such as this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-big-decimal